# Android Library Project Jar + IntelliJ IDEA 11

Tags: android, jar, android-library

I am using **IntelliJ IDEA 11.**

How can I create a JAR file for my android library Project?

I have a same android library project and its JAR file.I have managed to create a JAR file from `Module Settings->Project Settings->Artifacs->+`

I tried to compare my Jar file with the original one and the contents are different.

Can any one Confirm if my procedure is correct or not?

Comment: The resulting jar is usually generated under bin/ whenever you build your project. Perhaps you could use that instead? (Honestly, I wouldn't advise converting Android Library Projects to JAR files since they cannot be used for resources)

Comment: By default Jar builds are placed at `/out/production/<projectname>/classes.jar`

Comment: IntelliJ is the best IDE, but have many problems... example: tutorials for any questions are unsual, while for eclipse have a lot...

Change IDE... =/